# How to configure the processResources task in a Gradle Kotlin build

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the following in a groovy-based build script. How do I do the same in a kotlin-based script?

```
processResources {

    filesMatching('application.properties'){
        expand(project.properties)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think task should look like:

**Edit**: According this [comment](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/34#issuecomment-247497512) in [gradle/kotlin-dsl](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl) repository. Task configuration should work this way:

```
import org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources

apply {
    plugin("java")
}

(tasks.getByName("processResources") as ProcessResources).apply {
    filesMatching("application.properties") {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}
```

Which is pretty ugly. So i suggest following utility function for this purpose, until one upstream done:

```
configure<ProcessResources>("processResources") {
    filesMatching("application.properties") {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}

inline fun <reified C> Project.configure(name: String, configuration: C.() -> Unit) {
    (this.tasks.getByName(name) as C).configuration()
}
```

Comment: That looks like it should work but I get an error. I think it could be a bug. Logged it here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/in-gradle-script-kotlin-tasks-getbyname-with-closure-errors-with-value-is-null/20065/1

Comment: See the answer by @SoBeRich for a cleaner answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48241682/2491459

Comment: It was helpful. 
I'd like someone to make an groovy to kotlin-dsl converter!

Answer (score 27):

Why not to just use "withType" ?
I just mean (IMHO)

```
tasks {
  withType<ProcessResources> {
.. 
}
```

looks much better than

```
tasks {
  "processResources"(ProcessResources::class) {
.. 
}
```

So,

```
tasks.withType<ProcessResources> {
    //from("${project.projectDir}src/main/resources")
    //into("${project.buildDir}/whatever/")
    filesMatching("*.cfg") {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

With newer release you can just do:

```
tasks.processResources {}
```

or

```
tasks { processResources {} }
```

generated accessors are "lazy" so it has all the benefits and no downsides.

Comment: This should honestly be the correct answer. You would only need `"processResources"(ProcessResources::class)` if you weren't in a context where the Java plugin is applied.

Comment: @varcharmander also note what often escapes attention that in configures all tasks with such type for all `sourceSets` (e.g. also for `test` and any custom one).
Which is a common mistake when people do `compileJava {}` it only affects `JavaCompile` task for `main` `sourceSet`, so it always should be `withType<...>` for any type of tasks which has their instances run for different `sourceSets`

Answer (score 9):

With updates to the APIs in newer release of the Kotlin DSL and Gradle, you can do something like:

```
import org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources

plugins {
  java
}

tasks {
  "processResources"(ProcessResources::class) {
    filesMatching("application.properties") {
      expand(project.properties)
    }
  }
}
```

And also:

```
val processResources by tasks.getting(ProcessResources::class) {
  filesMatching("application.properties") {
    expand(project.properties)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is also IMO anti-pattern to get reference to `TaskProvider<..>` when you are not using that reference. 
aslo with "newer release" (after time of your anserwer) you can just do `tasks.processResources {}` or `tasks { processResources {} }` generated accessors are "lazy" so it has all the benefits and do downsides.