# How to replace a token in resource file using Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

What would be the equivament of the following in Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.kts)?

```
processResources {
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version: version]
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure the processResources task in a Gradle Kotlin build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096007/how-to-configure-the-processresources-task-in-a-gradle-kotlin-build)

Comment: No question you linked asks how to set processResources task and I'm asking how to rewrite a specific processResources function to Kotlin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's actually super easy:

```
tasks.processResources {
    expand("version" to project.version)
}
```

And then just put `${version}` in resource and it will be replaced with your project version

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It works and helped me with my issue as well. :)